# Como capturar uma linha de um arquivo e depois sobrescrevela?

Tags: php, fopen

Eu tenho que acessar um arquivo pelo php, esse arquivo tem uma variável na linha x eu quero pegar o conteúdo dessa variável, passo para uma condição, se diferente do esperado eu substituo o valor dessa variável por php, sem ter q acessar o arquivo manualmente.

Resumindo preciso acessar um arquivo.php de uma library via código php, verificar qual valor da variavel, se for diferente do valor esperado alterar seu valor, só seram 2 valores, produção e teste.

Exemplo

```
linha 12 $varivel = 'teste'; // arquivo.php

// tenho o código que captura o valor da variavel
$oqueTemLinha12 = 'o que tem la';

if ($variavel != 'teste') {
// alterar para produção, e vice e versa, o problema não é a condição e sim como obter um valor de um arquivo e como troca-lo se preciso
}
```

Comment: Você já está conseguindo abrir o arquivo, pelo menos?

Comment: Sim, ja consigo pegar o valor, só ainda não consegui substituir, eu uso o file pego a linha, pego o conteúdo, agora é só trocar. @FelipeAvelar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resposta correta

```
<?php

    // transforma o conteudo do arquivo em array
    $arquivo = file('Library/config/PaymentConfig.php');

    // armazena o que contem a linha 11
    $conteudoLinha = $arquivo[10];

    // captura apenas o valor da variavel
    function getAmbiente($conteudoLinha){
        $removeCaracteres = array('$ambiente = ', "'", ';');
        return str_replace($removeCaracteres, '', urldecode($conteudoLinha));
    }

    // seta o que vai conter na linha 11
    $arquivoe[10] = '$ambiente = "teste";' . "\n";

    // recria o arquivo com a linha 11 alterada
    file_put_contents('Library/config/PaymentConfig.php', implode("", $arquivo));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode reescrever parte do texto de um determinado arquivo, sem precisar gravar todo arquivo, utilizando o [fseek](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fseek.php), porém a quantidade de bytes (tamanho da frase) devem ser iguais.

Utilizando o fseek para posicionar o ponteiro para a posição  do arquivo, você deve sobrescrever o texto `$varivel = 'teste';`  por `$varivel = 'certo';` ou mesmo `$varivel = ''     ;`. Sempre mantendo os 7 caracteres, contando as aspas até o ponto e vírgula.